# How to test for link disappearing after the click in react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I have the component where when the link is clicked, some asynchronous action is performed to fetch additional replies and once that is completed and the component is rerendered the link disappears. Here is the component below:

```
import axios from "axios";
import Comment from "./Comment";

const CommentThread = ({ comment, comments, setComments }) => {
  const handleMoreReplies = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const response = await axios.get(
      `/api/comment_replies?comment_id=${comment.id}`
    );
    const replies = response.data;
    setComments(
      comments.map((c) => {
        if (c.id === comment.id) {
          return { ...c, replies: c.replies.concat(replies) };
        }
        return c;
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="parent-comment">
      <Comment {...comment} />
      <div className="replies">
        {comment.replies.map((reply) => {
          return <Comment key={reply.id} {...reply} />;
        })}
        {comment.replies_count === comment.replies.length ? null : (
          <a href="#" className="show_more" onClick={handleMoreReplies}>
            Show More Replies (2)
          </a>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CommentThread;
```

I want to test that when the button is clicked the link is no longer shown on the page. I can test if axios request has been sent with the correct url passed in but I can't test if the link disappeared as if I do `waitForElementToBeRemoved` I get an error that it can't read the property `data` of `undefined` meaning that the response is `undefined`.

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";

import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import CommentThread from "../components/CommentThread";

jest.mock("axios");

const comment = {
  id: "4b2d74e6-7d1a-4ba3-9e95-0f52ee8ebc6e",
  author: "Reed Fisher",
  body: "Sint in in sunt amet.",
  postedAt: 1550488214207,
  replies_count: 3,
  replies: [
    {
      id: "116dbd01-d5f3-4dfb-afeb-f822a9264a5e",
      comment_id: "4b2d74e6-7d1a-4ba3-9e95-0f52ee8ebc6e",
      author: "Kathleen Nikolaus",
      body: "Officia suscipit sint sint impedit nemo. Labore aut et quia quasi ut. Eos voluptatibus quidem eius delectus beatae excepturi.",
      postedAt: 1550419941546,
    },
  ],
};

const comments = [
   {
    id: "4b2d74e6-7d1a-4ba3-9e95-0f52ee8ebc6e",
    author: "Reed Fisher",
    body: "Sint in in sunt amet.",
    postedAt: 1550488214207,
    replies_count: 3,
    replies: [
      {
        id: "116dbd01-d5f3-4dfb-afeb-f822a9264a5e",
        comment_id: "4b2d74e6-7d1a-4ba3-9e95-0f52ee8ebc6e",
        author: "Kathleen Nikolaus",
        body: "Officia suscipit sint sint impedit nemo. Labore aut et quia quasi ut. Eos voluptatibus quidem eius delectus beatae excepturi.",
        postedAt: 1550419941546,
      },
    ],
  }


test("setComments called when the link is clicked", async () => {
  const user = userEvent.setup();

  const response = {
    data: [
      {
        id: "116dbd01-d5f3-4dfb-afeb-f822a9264a5f",
        comment_id: "4b2d74e6-7d1a-4ba3-9e95-0f52ee8ebc6e",
        author: "Srdjan",
        body: "Officia suscipit sint sint impedit nemo. Labore aut et quia quasi ut. Eos voluptatibus quidem eius delectus beatae excepturi.",
        postedAt: 1550419941546,
      },
      {
        id: "116dbd01-d5f3-4dfb-afeb-f822a9264a5d",
        comment_id: "4b2d74e6-7d1a-4ba3-9e95-0f52ee8ebc6e",
        author: "Max",
        body: "Officia suscipit sint sint impedit nemo. Labore aut et quia quasi ut. Eos voluptatibus quidem eius delectus beatae excepturi.",
        postedAt: 1550419941546,
      },
    ],
  };
  const func = jest.fn();
  render(
    <CommentThread comment={comment} comments={comments} setComments={func} />
  );
  const link = screen.getByRole("link", { name: /Show More Replies/ });

  axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(response);
  await user.click(link);
  expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    `/api/comment_replies?comment_id=${comment.id}`
  );
});
```

To be able to test that the link disappeared I would need to somehow grab the axios response from the server and populate the comment with additional replies.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to understand quickly your code and it looks like the `setComments` callback method is somehow used to update the `comments` in `comment` ;)?

So what we want to do is to use that method callback value and rerender the component with new updated `comment` object. Then we can actually query if the link is still there.

One quick solution would be:

```js
(...)
  const func = jest.fn();
  const commentThread = render(
    <CommentThread comment={comment} comments={comments} setComments={func} />
  );
  const link = screen.getByRole("link", { name: /Show More Replies/ });
 
  axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce(response);
  await user.click(link);
  expect(axios.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    `/api/comment_replies?comment_id=${comment.id}`
  );

  const newComments = func.mock.calls[0][0]

  commentThread.rerender(
    <CommentThread comment={newComments.find(({ id }) => id === comment.id )} comments={comments} setComments={func} />
  );

  expect(screen.queryByRole("link", { name: /Show More Replies/ })).toBeNull();
}
```